# "None" in Python code breaks code suggestions in vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylance

[ This was a bug in vscode < v1.71, see my comment with additional screenshots. ]

I've got a weird issue in vscode. For some reason, code completion of **c.** stops working after the first **None** in the Python code, as shown in below screenshot.

[image: After first None, it is like c. contains nothing]

This is the complete Card class (complete source code, see link below):

```py
from dataclasses import asdict
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses import field

@dataclass
class Card:
    summary: str = None
    owner: str = None
    state: str = "todo"
    id: int = field(default=None, compare=False)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        return Card(**d)
    def to_dict(self):
        return asdict(self)
```

It is like if **c.** contains nothing after that. I just get "No suggestions." when using **Ctrl+.** at **c.**.

If i put None in quotes, like "None", suggestions works for following rows. Until the next **None** that is.

If I change to **False**, suggestions works for following rows. It just seems to happen for **None**!

It is also contained within the function scope too.

Any idea why this is happening?

The code is used in the Pytest book and can be download from [Python Testing with pytest, Second Edition](https://pragprog.com/titles/bopytest2/python-testing-with-pytest-second-edition/#extracts).

The file my problem is from is: code/ch2/test_card.py

**Reinstalled vscode**
The problem remains after a complete reinstallation of vscode, including manually deleting the "~/.config/Code/" and "~/.vscode/" folders.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.10.4 virtual environment using pyenv
- vscode extensions:

  - HTML CSS Support
  - Python

    - That autoinstalled Pylance, Jubyter, Jupyter Keymap and Jupyter Notebook Renderers
  - Python Environment Manager
  - rust-analyzer

Comment: If you put brackets around the `c.id is None`, does auto-completion now work?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6g0K.gif Can you [edit] your question to add more details about your environment?

Comment: @smac89 It is the same with parenthesis like "assert (c.summary is None)", no suggestions after that.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've added some environment info now.

Comment: I have no problem here. Can you describe your problem clearly, or how do you define Card?

Comment: @JialeDu It is the project code for the Pytest book at https://pragprog.com/titles/bopytest2/python-testing-with-pytest-second-edition/#extracts - where you can download it. The file my problem is from is code/ch2/test_card.py. I've added this info to the post as well.

Comment: @tdelaney I've added the class to the post now.

Comment: I have also uninstalled vscode, deleted its two folders in my ~/ and then reinstalled vscode. The problem remains.

Comment: i see the same problem, ubuntu 21.04. Same thing happens with other None things like `if c.summy is None:`. Glitch in the matrix?

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks, actually makes me calmer, that it isn't something unique on my computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This was a bug in vscode < v1.71**

I was just about to get started thoroughly testing the suggestions @mpette, @JialeDu and  @Okken provided in their comments.

However, I was met with that v1.71 had been installed, and now it works with the original code, as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Suggestions after None works gain]

So it seems to me this was indeed a bug in the previous version of vscode, as the Python extensions still needs to be reloaded for their updates to take affect:

[image: Python extensions not updated]

After reloading them, suggestions keeps working as they should :)

Thanks everyone who so kindly tried to help me get this fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use type hints, I suggest you configure vscode to do Mypy type checking to avoid these kind of errors.

If you annotate the type as `str` and then assign it a value of `None`, and you have Mypy type checking, this will trigger an incompatible type warning.

[image: screenshot vscode incompatible type]

Because you have annotated the type as `str`. Vscode will think that the 2nd assertion is unreachable:

```py
c = Card()
assert c.summary is None # assertion always fails because c.summary is string
assert c.owner is None # this statement is unreachable
```

The 2nd assertion
Screenshot shows that vscode thinks 2nd assertion is never reached because the 1st assertion will always fail because a string type will never be none.
[image: Screenshot never reached]

To correct use the `Optional` type hint when assigning `None`.

```py
from dataclasses import asdict
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses import field

from typing import Optional, Any, Dict

@dataclass
class Card:
    summary: Optional[str] = None
    owner: Optional[str] = None
    state: str = "todo"
    id: Optional[int] = field(default=None, compare=False)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d: Dict[str, Any]) -> "Card":
        return Card(**d)
    def to_dict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return asdict(self)
```

As a final point, I think you have absolutely done the right thing. In my view, autocomplete is critically important in avoiding mistakes. If autocomplete isn't working you should stop, figure out why, and do not continue until you get autocomplete working again.

Comment: I will try and configure mypy in the weekend and get back about if that changes things. I also just tried using PyCharm Pro, and there it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

##### Seems to be related to type annotations.

If you remove variable type annotation in `Card` class in `cards_proj\src\cards\api.py` file. Then the intellisense will work fine.

**Source code:**

```py
class Card:
    summary: str = None
    owner: str = None
    state: str = "todo"
    id: int = field(default=None, compare=False)
```

**change into:**

```py
class Card:
    summary = None
    owner = None
    state = "todo"
    id = field(default=None, compare=False)
```

[image]

If you only remove type annotations for some variables, like below.

```py
class Card:
    summary: str = None
    owner: str = None
    state = "todo"
    id = field(default=None, compare=False)
```

**Then when the variable with the type annotation is assigned none, the following intellisense will be invalid.**

[image]

*`summary` is `None`, the following code cannot get suggestions*

[image]

*`summary` is not `None`, the following code can get suggestions*

[image]

*`summary` is not `None`, but `owner` is `None`, the following code cannot get suggestions*

Comment: Just tried that, but no. Removing the type hint didn't change anything. Also I just tried opening the code in PyCharm Pro, and there it works just fine with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a quirk of VS Code on Ubuntu combined with sloppy type hinting.

I really should have used the types as mpette noted, using `Optional[X] = None`:

```py
@dataclass
class Card:
    summary: Optional[str] = None
    owner: Optional[str] = None
    state: str = "todo"
    id: Optional[int] = field(default=None, compare=False)
```

Or even the newer bar form `X|None`:

```py
@dataclass
class Card:
    summary: str|None = None
    owner: str|None = None
    state: str = "todo"
    id: int|None = field(default=None, compare=False)
```

However, even on a mac, the second form seems to confuse VSCode.

Also, VSCode on my mac seems to deal with the original form just fine. Odd that it's different behavior on Ubuntu.

Comment: I will add the "str | None" to the code, unless there is a risk doing so will have impact on how the tests and exercises in your book works?